# Printing file to replicate /? flag in command prompt

Tags: python, windows

I have a large file I'd like to display in the terminal, but in manageable chunks. Ideally, I'd like to show it in a manner similar to using the `/?` flag in the command prompt, such as `start /?` where each chunk is followed by a "Press any key to continue..."  and then that line is overwritten.

I thought I could do this by printing the prompt with just a carriage return and an input like so:

```
# printing lines
print('Press any key to continue...')
_ = input()
```

But they cursor jumps down below the last printed line after `input`.

Is there a way to do this so a large file can be displayed in chunks, asks a user to press enter, and then continues printing while overwriting the prompt to continue?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share a [mcve]. How do you display a file content in the terminal so far?  Maybe the following could do the trick? `_ = os.system( 'type "path_to_file"|more')`

Comment: @JosefZ Using a pipe with the `more` and `type` commands produces a different result, and requires a user to know the `more` subcommands to operate the page (such as pressing space vs enter); your MRE was already given, with `start /?` on a Windows CLI, replication of that in Python is desired. I have also shown what sequence of `print` + `input` does not work due to a CRLF on `input` buffer flushing.

Comment: Again: please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. What's wrong on `os.system( 'start /?')` - if your only [mcve] is `start /?` (no _Python_ code)?

Comment: @JosefZ I think you should re-read the question, I'm not trying to run the `start /?` command at all...

Comment: Again: *please*  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].